# Find the value of a link and use that link as the class name for a parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hey guys – I have the following HTML:

```
<div>
    <span class="icon">
        <a href="#">Technology</a>
    </span>
</div>

<div>
    <span class="icon">
        <a href="#">Design</a>
    </span>
</div>

<div>
    <span class="icon">
        <a href="#">Management</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

I'm looking for a short and sweet jQuery snippet that will detect the value in the link, and add that value as a class name for to the span, resulting in the following:

```
<div>
    <span class="icon Technology">
        <a href="#">Technology</a>
    </span>
</div>

<div>
    <span class="icon Design">
        <a href="#">Design</a>
    </span>
</div>

<div>
    <span class="icon Management">
        <a href="#">Management</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

I am using:

```
var categoryName = $(".icon a", this).html();
$(".icon").addClass(categoryName);
```

But it is only taking the value of the first link and applying that as the class name for each span.

Thanks for the help as always!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `.each()` to iterate over all span with class `icon`.:

```
$('.icon').each(function(){
    $(this).addClass($(this).find('a').html())
})
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bEt2e/)**

Answer (score 5):

```
$(".icon").each(function(){

    $(this).addClass($(this).find("a").html());

});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ppwBs/)

---

You can also do this with a loop:

```
var spans = $(".icon");

for(var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++)
{
    var cspan = $(spans[i]);
    $(cspan).addClass($(cspan).find("a").html());
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ppwBs/2/)

Comment: In my defense, he changed his answer to be the same as mine after I had already added mine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

1) **[$.each()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)** to loop through the span with class `icon`

2) **[.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)** to find the child anchor inside your span

3) **[.text()](https://api.jquery.com/text/)** to get the text of the found anchor:

```
$.each($('span.icon'), function(){
    $(this).addClass($(this).find('a').text());
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s9zLL/)**

Answer (score 2):

You can run this on page load or under some event:

```
$(".icon").each(function(){
   var name = $(this).find("a").text();
   $(this).addClass(name);
});
```